# Determine unchecked boxes in a submitted form using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I just cant figure this one out:

I have a list of items:

- Front and Back of Title -
- Drivers License -
- Vehicle Insurance -
- Proof of Residence -
- Proof of Income -
- 4 References

And a form where people check off those items.
When they press submit, I have some code that gets the values they checked, and puts them in an array like this:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Front and Back of Title
 [1] => Drivers License
 [2] => Vehicle Insurance
 [3] => Proof of Residence
 [4] => Proof of Income
 [5] => 4 References
)
```

So the array contains any values they checked..

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Full Title Loan Applicaiton">Full Title Loan Applicaiton <br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Front and Back of Title">Front and Back of Title<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Drivers License">Drivers License<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Vehicle Insurance">Vehicle Insurance<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Proof of Residence">Proof of Residence<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Proof of Income">Proof of Income<br />
```

How would derive what values they DID not check?

Comment: Are the checkboxes created dynamically from an array of those items?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Full Title Loan Applicaiton">Full Title Loan Applicaiton <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Front and Back of Title">Front and Back of Title<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Drivers License">Drivers License<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Vehicle Insurance">Vehicle Insurance<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Proof of Residence">Proof of Residence<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Proof of Income">Proof of Income<br />

Comment: You can't just check which spots in the array are null?

Comment: @user1789437, do not put code in the comments reedit your question to show whatever extra you need to show.

Comment: You'd think that after 42 questions the OP would know how to edit their question

Comment: Have you checked how `$REQUEST['check_list']` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the item is in the array. I'm not sure how your logic is set up, but I'm assigning a variable here:

```
$driversLicence = in_array('Drivers License', $_REQUEST['check_list'], true);
```

See [`in_array`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).